# Hide bottom tab naivgation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have a bottom tab bar that locates in app.js. And I have the class where I want to hide the bottom bar. In page home.js I have 2 classes. 1st one is main (is the list of articles), the second one is for button page navigation (in this class I display articles). How I can hide bottom tab navigation in the second page (where articles are displayed). I have tried tabBarVisible: false, but this does not work. Help me, please. 
Code:

```html
// app.js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Главная',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

  Courses:{
    screen:Courses,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Courses',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-school" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Editor:{
    screen:Editor,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Editor',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-document" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

},{
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor:'#db0202',
    inactiveTintColor:'grey',
    style:{
      fontSize:3,
      height:45,
      backgroundColor:'white',
      borderTopWidth:0,
      elevation: 5
    }
  }
});



export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

```html
// home.js

import React from 'react';
import { Font } from 'expo';

import { Button, View, Text, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, ListView, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions,
ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Courses from './Courses'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <ScrollView
      >
<ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
         renderRow={rowData => (
           <>
      <Text
               onPress={() => {
                 /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                 this.props.navigation.navigate("Articles", {
                   otherParam: rowData.article_title,
                 });
               }}
             >
               {rowData.article_title}
             </Text>
              
           </>
         )}
       />
       </ScrollView
       >
</SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}


class ArticleScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;

    return {
      title: params ? params.otherParam : '',
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const article_title = params ? params.otherParam : '';


    return (
        <Text>{article_title}</Text>
    );
  }
}


  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
        navigationOptions: {
       header: null,
    }
      },
      Articles: {
        screen: ArticleScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );




  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }



  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make StackNavigator as main Navigator and TabBar as a sub navigator:

```
const TabBar =  createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs, TabNavigatorConfig);

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        TabBar,
        WelcomeScene: { screen:Scenes.WelcomeScene },
        HomeScene: { screen: HomeScene }
   }
```

Using this when you go the second screen Tabbar will hide automatically.

Comment: In home.js, and use only one Container.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```js
class ArticleScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
     title: params ? params.otherParam : '',
     tabBarVisible: false
    };
  };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. Create Tab navigator and pass it down to Stack navigator as one of the screen,  when you navigate to the Articles, it will hide the tab bar...

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Главная',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
          ),
        },
      },

      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Courses',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-school" color={tintColor} size={24} />
          ),
        },
      },
      Editor: {
        screen: Editor,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Editor',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-document" color={tintColor} size={24} />
          ),
        },
      },

    }, {
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#db0202',
        inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
        style: {
          fontSize: 3,
          height: 45,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 5,
        },
      },
    });


    const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Home: {
          screen: TabNavigator,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          },
        },
        Articles: {
            screen: ArticleScreen,
          },
          // add screens here which you want to hide the tab bar
        });

    export default createAppContainer(stackNavigator);
```